# Accessing @android:id/list ListView from code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml

In my Android application, I add a ListView element (for example) in the main.xml layout file this way:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/myList">
```

Then I can access it from my MainActivity using:

```
final ListView resultList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
```

But how can I access such a ListView if I use the following ID in the layout file?

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list">
```

I want to access it from my MainActivity (which extends ListActivity).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can get it with `ListView list = getListView();` from within your ListActivity

Comment: Thank you :) Probably a stupid question, but I couldn't find any description on the Android developer pages.

Answer (score 18):

> you can get it with ListView list = getListView();

Or:

```
(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: Thank you :) The first option works fine. But the alternative doesn't work for me!?

Comment: Oops: missed android.R. **id** .list

Comment: Thanks! I had to choose one answer. So I chose the faster one, sorry.

Comment: Lol, I don't care about the rep :)

Comment: like that :-) just wanted to explain it to you ;-)